# То, что там было, — это был полный писец/песец

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`То, что там было, — это был полный писец/песец.`

Comment: А есть разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *То, что там было, — это был полный **песец**.*

**ПЕСЕЦ**, -сца; м. 1. Хищное млекопитающее сем. псовых с ценным серовато-дымчатым (голубым) мехом; полярная лисица. Голубой п. Охота на песца. Следы песца.

**Из  [статьи](https://muzei-moskvy.ru/pisec-u-molodezi-smysl-i-znacenie/)**

Песец стал одним из самых популярных **символов** современной молодежи. Песец обладает **оригинальным и запоминающимся внешним видом.** Его симпатичная мордочка с большими глазками, пушистые уши и пушистый хвост вызывают положительные эмоции у большинства молодых людей.

Песец символизирует **свободу и непринужденный образ жизни.** Молодежь стремится отделиться от общепринятых стереотипов и запретов, поэтому они идентифицируют себя с песцом, который ведет свободный образ жизни **в дикой природе.**

Слово «песец» имеет характерный смысловой оттенок, который несет в себе некоторую **иронию и самоиронию**. Молодежь использует это слово для выражения **саркастической оценки чего-либо или самокритики.** Часто песец ассоциируется **с нестандартными или эксцентричными вещами,** что отличается от общепринятых стандартов.

Comment: А зачем тире? То что там было, это половина песца.

Comment: https://content-28.foto.my.mail.ru/community/kv.vopros/_groupsphoto/h-19893.jpg

Comment: *Песец* значит *хаос*.

Comment: Ну да, эксцентрично немного...

Comment: Что с форумом? Он, что ль-с, обновился?

Comment: А что с ним случилось?